# Why ALT+. (last parameter) does not work in Bash?

Tags: terminal, iterm

I am used to it from Linux terminals. Using both Terminal and iTerm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> instead, this will work in both Terminal and iTerm.

Answer (score 4):

By default, the Alt-key doesn’t work in MacOS (OSX) Terminal. Simple solution for this problem:

Terminal > Preferences > Settings > Keyboard
Just check `Use option as meta key` at the bottom!

This will disable Mac extended characters (ex. Option+g = © Copyright char), but no worry if you dont need them.